# Add argument to cakephp 1.3 route

Tags: routes, cakephp-1.3

I have an MVC structure, `User`.
It manages three types of users, users, clients and tenants; it's all done from the `User`.
What i need is a hidden parameter, that will be added to each route, that will tell the controller how to do it's job.

examples:

`/clients/unverified/5` will be route to `/users/unverified/client/5`
and `/tenants/unverified/5` will be route to `/users/unverified/tenant/5`

If you have a better idea of how it should be done, i will also appreciate it.

Comment: Please explain...little bit more for clarity...

Comment: Not sure what else can i add. the basic idea is to get the same controller>action for different routes, with a hidden parameter that will tell which route is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same controller action as shown below:

```
Router::connect('/clients/unverified/:limit',
                array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'unverified',
                'client','5')
);
Router::connect('/tenants/unverified/:limit',
                array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'unverified',
               'tenants','5')
);
Router::connect('/whatever/unverified/:limit',
                array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'unverified',
               'whatever','5')
);
```

In users controller

```
 # $type would be clients/ tenants/ watever
 # $limit would be 5 
function unverified($type='user',$limit=5){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options jump out at me:

`1.` Use `Router::connect()` in `/app/config/routes.php`:

This method should result in the ID being passed in without needing to specify it (as well as any other arguments).

```
Router::connect('/clients/unverified/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'unverified', 'client'));
Router::connect('/tenants/unverified/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'unverified', 'tenants'));
```

[More info on routing in Cake 1.3.](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#routes-configuration)

`2.` Create `clients` and `tenants` controllers, `unverified` actions and simply redirect them to the `users` controller